# Spring batch admin. Meta Tables remain empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am following [spring batch admin](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-batch-admin-tutorial/).
I want to use database for saving meta data values.
My meta data tables are created, but data does not go to those tables.  It still uses in memory for storing metadata.

I know spring uses `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` as the implementation class for `jobRepository` bean to store data in memory, and we have to change it to
`JobRepositoryFactoryBean` if we want to store meta data in database.

However, even after changing it, I see no effect. (I have cleaned and recompiled, no issues there)

I have wasted some time searching it, but with no success. Can any one help?

My batch-oracle.properties file is-

```
batch.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.45:1521:devdb
batch.jdbc.user=hsdndad
batch.jdbc.password=isjdsn

batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql
batch.business.schema.script=classpath:oracle/initial-query.sql
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer
batch.database.incrementer.parent=sequenceIncrementerParent
batch.lob.handler.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler
batch.grid.size=2
batch.jdbc.pool.size=6
batch.verify.cursor.position=true
batch.isolationlevel=ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
batch.table.prefix=BATCH_
```

Comment: is the job running

Comment: yes . . and It is showing completed status

Comment: please show the parts where you changed the configuration

Comment: After some digging I came to know about the particular convention of properties file(earlier I was giving it name batch-default.properties) . . so now I think it is trying to insert but throwing some SERIALIZABLE exceptions.

Comment: Can you post your JobRepository configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> After some digging I came to know about the particular convention of properties file(earlier I was giving it name batch-default.properties) . . so now I think it is trying to insert but throwing some SERIALIZABLE exceptions. – Nirbhay Mishra

Try changing the isolationLevelForCreate for the JobRepository to ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED